# Is it possible to program for Sony Ericsson mobile phones(symbian) using Visual Studio?

Tags: symbian, smartphone

This question is just out of curiosity, I own a P1i and it would be nice to play with it :)

A link to some documentation would be fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't officially supported, but apparently you can get it to work:

http://www3.symbian.com/faq.nsf/7b5405edb1250e7c802569ee005d054e/30398b3e9500a24d80256c7f00693a91?OpenDocument

Plus there are some 3rd party solutions out there if you google

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the VS supports makefile based projects as well so you can pretty much develop anything as long as there's a CLI based compiler for it. Sometimes, if you're lucky, Intellisense can pick up the headers and do autocompletion.

EDIT: To do this in VS2K5, do the following:

Select File->New->Project...
In the dialog, select the General type under Visual C++ branch of the left hand tree view. The right hand list should have a 'Makefile Project'. Highlight that, select a project name and then OK. You now get a wizard that allows you to set up the build command lines (what version of make and so on).

You have to manually create and update the makefile with the source files but everything else works as if it were a native VS project (F7 to build, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - using older versions (VC++.NET 2003) and Carbide.vs